# Travelling nested object and building a flat object from it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a an array of objects that I need to traverse and as the depth goes I need to assign a treeLevel attribute on each node.
I have created the following plunker, https://plnkr.co/edit/wou4Vj?p=info
I have figured out the travelling part but I am not able to get on how to assign the treeLevels on each node.

```
sampleInput = [
    {
      sectorName: 'a',
      sectorType: 'a',
      sectors: [
        {
          sectorName: 'a-a1',
          sectorType: 'a-a1',
          sectors: [
            {
              sectorName: 'a-a1-a1',
              sectorType: 'a-a1-a1',  
            },
            {
              sectorName: 'a-a1-a2',
              sectorType: 'a-a1-a2',  
            },
            {
              sectorName: 'a-a1-a3',
              sectorType: 'a-a1-a3',
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          sectorName: 'a-a2',
          sectorType: 'a-a2',
        },
        {
          sectorName: 'a-a3',
          sectorType: 'a-a3',
          sectors: [
            {
              sectorName: 'a-a3-a1',
              sectorType: 'a-a3-a1',  
              sectors: [
                {
                  sectorName: 'a-a3-a1-a1',
                  sectorType: 'a-a3-a1-a1',
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      sectorName: 'b',
      sectorType: 'b',
    },
    {
      sectorName: 'c',
      sectorType: 'c',
      sectors: [
        {
            sectorName: 'c-c1',
            sectorType: 'c-c2',
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Below is what I am expecting as output,

```
"[
  {"sectorName":"a","sectorType":"a","$$treeLevel":0},
  {"sectorName":"a-a1","sectorType":"a-a1","$$treeLevel":1},
  {"sectorName":"a-a1-a1","sectorType":"a-a1-a1","$$treeLevel":0},
  {"sectorName":"a-a1-a2","sectorType":"a-a1-a2","$$treeLevel":0},
  {"sectorName":"a-a1-a3","sectorType":"a-a1-a3","$$treeLevel":0},
  {"sectorName":"a-a2","sectorType":"a-a2","$$treeLevel":0},
  {"sectorName":"a-a3","sectorType":"a-a3","$$treeLevel":1},
  {"sectorName":"a-a3-a1","sectorType":"a-a3-a1","$$treeLevel":2},
  {"sectorName":"a-a3-a1-a1","sectorType":"a-a3-a1-a1","$$treeLevel":3},    
  {"sectorName":"b","sectorType":"b","$$treeLevel":0},
  {"sectorName":"c","sectorType":"c","$$treeLevel":0},
  {"sectorName":"c-c1","sectorType":"c-c2","$$treeLevel":1}
]"
```

The logic to increment treeLevel is that if we have a sectors array as part of current object, copy the current object assign it treeLevel, increment treeLevel and then recurse.
But do note that the direct child of same parent will get assigned correct treelevel. For example above `{"sectorName":"a-a3","sectorType":"a-a3","$$treeLevel":1},` 'a-a3' being direct child of 'a-a1' will get assigned treeLevel as 1 and not zero.

Can some one help me out on this one. I just need to figure out on how to get the treelevel assignment working. I am open to all solutions, recursive, non-recursivem, using lodash lib and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why does a deeper level yield a level of zero in the wanted result?

Comment: The treeLevel are supposed to indicate depth. So if your object does not have any more children sectors in it I am assigning a treeLevel of zero to indicate no more depth. However later I updated my code and removed the treeLevel altogether from objects that do not have any children, as it made more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the actual level and increment it on every nested level.

```js
function getFlat(array) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function flat(level) {
        return function (o) {
            result.push({ sectorName: o.sectorName, sectorType: o.sectorType, $$treeLevel: level });
            o.sectors && o.sectors.forEach(flat(level + 1));
        };
    }(0));
    return result;
}

var data = [{ sectorName: 'a', sectorType: 'a', sectors: [{ sectorName: 'a-a1', sectorType: 'a-a1', sectors: [{ sectorName: 'a-a1-a1', sectorType: 'a-a1-a1', }, { sectorName: 'a-a1-a2', sectorType: 'a-a1-a2', }, { sectorName: 'a-a1-a3', sectorType: 'a-a1-a3', }] }, { sectorName: 'a-a2', sectorType: 'a-a2', }, { sectorName: 'a-a3', sectorType: 'a-a3', sectors: [{ sectorName: 'a-a3-a1', sectorType: 'a-a3-a1', sectors: [{ sectorName: 'a-a3-a1-a1', sectorType: 'a-a3-a1-a1', }] }] }] }, { sectorName: 'b', sectorType: 'b', }, { sectorName: 'c', sectorType: 'c', sectors: [{ sectorName: 'c-c1', sectorType: 'c-c2', }] }],
    result = getFlat(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The flat() did the trick. This somehow missed when i wrote the traverse(). I was more focused on traversing the array which it did but I did not pay attention on the treeLevel prop. Thanks...